# XSS on jsbin.com

Tags: javascript, xss, security

Anyone know if jsbin.com implements any protection for XSS or other javascript attacks?

I see jsbin links used fairly regularly on sites like this one and I can't find any indication from the site one way or another.  If it does implement counter measures, what kinds of things does it block out.  If not, I should probably be more careful about which links I choose to click.

Comment: Your best bet is to send the developer, Remy Sharp, an email and ask him directly.

Comment: Can you give an example of an attack you'd be concerned about?  XSS is just the unintentional execution of user-supplied Javascript, but that's impossible on JS Bin because the site exists for the purpose of executing arbitrary user-supplied Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess an unfriendly script could do a denial of service on jsbin by continually scripting a ‘save to public URL’ submission to clog the database up. And of course anyone could post a security hole exploit script which would infect people with old browsers and plugins; that might also get jsbin on Google's blocklist.

That's about all though... there are no user credentials to steal or nefarious things to do with people's accounts and privileges because there are no accounts or privileges.

> I should probably be more careful about which links I choose to click.

Yes, that seems reasonable.

Comment: Hmm, I see there's no way to list or delete your creations though, so although you could get your code running on someone else's browser, I guess there's no URLs on jsbin.com you could call that would do anything malicious with their login... And if you want to post a security hole exploit script, I guess you could just put that on your own server anyway (although people might be more likely to trust a jsbin.com URL)...